# How to find the difference between months

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I am trying to find the difference between two month values. The input month values are in format YYYYMMM. And I want the result concatenated with a character to be able to filter on a field in my table.

So for example - I want to find the difference between 2019M04 (i.e. April 2019) and 2018M12 (i.e. Dec 2018). The desired result here is 04, so I want it concatenated with letter 'T'. Hence my filter will be on field T04.

The basic idea is to dynamically identify columns to apply filter on based on month value which is a variable.

I have tried using Datediff but could not get any result. Maybe I am doing something wrong.. Please help!!

Sample Data -

T01 T02 T03 T04 T05 T06

1.2 1.3 1.5 1.6 1.7 1.2

2.4 2.5 2.7 2.4 2.7 2.8

Comment: Right, sorry... I am using Hadoop database.

Comment: Please also provide some sample data and the query you've already attempted.

Comment: Sample data -

T01 T02 T03 T04 T05 T06
1.2 1.3 1.5 1.6 1.7 1.2
2.4 2.5 2.7 2.4 2.7 2.8

Comment: Hadoop is a file storage system.  Are you using Hive?

Comment: Yes, I am using HIVE

Answer (score 1):

You can convert to numbers and do arithmetic.  Most databases support `left()` and `right()` string functions.

To get the difference as a number, you can do:

```
select ( ( cast(left(yyyymmm1, 4) as int) * 12 + cast(right(yyyymm1, 2) as int) - 1 ) -
         ( cast(left(yyyymmm2, 4) as int) * 12 + cast(right(yyyymm2, 2) as int) - 1 ) 
       ) as diff
```

You can then format this however you like.

In Hive, try this:

```
select ( ( cast(substr(yyyymmm1, 1, 4) as int) * 12 + cast(substr(yyyymm1, 5, 2) as int) - 1 ) -
         ( cast(substr(yyyymmm2, 1, 4) as int) * 12 + cast(substr(yyyymm2, 5, 2) as int) - 1 ) 
       ) as diff
```

Comment: Apparently HIVE doesn't accept left() or right(). So I tried substr() instead. 

But my query is giving NULL output

select ( ( cast(substr('2019M06', 4) as int) * 12 + cast(substr('2019M06', -2) as int) - 1 ) -
         ( cast(substr('2018M12', 4) as int) * 12 + cast(substr('2018M12', -2) as int) - 1 ) 
       ) as diff
       from xyz

Comment: Ok so, the substr i posted earlier is working fine for right() replacement. but for left() it isn't. The below worked well -

select ( ( cast(substr('2019M06',0,4) as int) * 12 + cast(substr('2019M06',-2) as int) - 1 ) -
         ( cast(substr('2018M12',0,4) as int) * 12 + cast(substr('2018M12',-2) as int) - 1 ) 
       ) as diff
       from xyz

Thanks Gordon, for your help. I am new to SQLs, so I was staggering around this.